# Динамический массив с заменой элементов

Tags: c++, массивы

Дана задача: создать динамический массив с указателями, с возможностью ввода пользователем элементов массива. Так же в массиве элементы 0 должны быть заменены на 1.

Мой код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main()
{
    int a, b, c;
    int* array[] = {&a, &b, &c};
    cout<<"Enter elements: ";
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {   
        cin>>array[];      
        if(array[] == 0)
            array[] == 0);
    }
    cout<<"Result: ";   
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cout<<array[]<<" ";
    cout<<endl;
}
```

Вопрос: программа не компилируется, ругается на использование cout и cin.

Comment: Помимо отсутствия пространства имен - что, по-вашему, должна делать, например, конструкция `cin>>array[];`? Компилятор "истинно негодует" (с) Отсутствие указания пространства имен - наименьшая из ошибок вашего кода. Ну, разве что еще необъявленная переменная `n` той же степени ерундовости...

Comment: выводить элементы массива...

Comment: Элементы массива выводятся *по одному*.

Comment: Ну что сказать?..  От самого начала кода и до самого не возвращающего значения, ясно что вы не изучив ничего, пытаетсь писать что то...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### У вас не указано пространство имён `std`.

Похоже, ваш вопрос заключается в том, почему компилятор выдаёт ошибку на cin и cout. Вы забыли указать пространство имён, вам надо либо использовать `using namespace std`, либо (и это лучше) указать пространство имён явно:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    int a, b, c;
    int n = 3;
    int* array[] = {&a, &b, &c};
    std::cout << "Enter elements: ";
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {   
        std::cin >> *(array[i]);      
        if(*(array[i]) == 0)
        {
            *(array[i]) = 1;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "Result: ";   
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        std::cout << *(array[i]) <<" ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

PS. И зачем вы подключили `string`, если его не используете?

PS2. Похоже при вставке кода у вас что-то сползло и приведённый код не компилируется. Я не стал исправлять эти ошибки, исправления только по вопросу. Надеюсь, остальные ошибки (опечатки) вы сможете исправить сами.

Comment: возвращающего значения нет.. и добущенные ошибки оставили

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Если вы про отсутствие `return` в `main` - то формально оно не обязательно.

Comment: Там столько ошибок, что я не рискнул их исправлять... Только по вопросу исправил.

Comment: Вот, некоторый вариант исправления, но это изврат на мой взгляд...

Comment: Если пишете ответ с полным кодом, то нужно исправлять ошибки. Или покажите только фрагмент, но в ответе не должны быть ошибки, особенно  такие,    Я так понимаю

Comment: Ладно, учту в дальнейшем. Текущий код компилируется: http://cpp.sh/43frx