# Поломка ввода/вывода в коде с указателями

Tags: c++, указатели

Дана задача:ввести 3 вещественные переменные, на них навести указатели, с их помощью в 1 и 3 поменять значения, 2 увеличить в 3 раза.
Мой код:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
double a,b,c, temp;
cin >> a,b,c;
double* i_ptr = &a;
double* i_prt = &b;
double* i_rtp = &c;
a = *i_rtp;
temp=*i_rtp;
c = *i_rtp; 
cout << *i_ptr * 3 << endl;
cout << *i_prt << *i_rtp << endl;
}
```

Как исправить ошибку с не распознаванием cin и cout?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Динамический массив с заменой элементов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/922783/%d0%94%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2-%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2)

Comment: 1) пространство имен std  2) std::cin >> a >> b >> c;

Answer (score 3):

либо писать `std::cin` и `std::cout`

или в самом начале программы написать строку `using namespace std;`

Comment: Проблема сохранилась

Comment: Вы написали using namespace std; ? Тогда проблема не могла сохраниться... using namespace std; надо написать сразу после #include , перед main .

Answer (score 2):

И что вы этим добились по сути?

```
double* i_rtp = &c;
a = *i_rtp;             // a = c
temp=*i_rtp;            // temp = c
c = *i_rtp;             // с = с

cout << *i_ptr * 3 << endl;         // a*3
cout << *i_prt << *i_rtp << endl;   // b  c
```

К чему эти телодвижения?

Не считая того, что

```
cin >> a,b,c;
```

это просто считать `a`, и два выражения без каких-либо действий - `b` и `c`...

Проблема у вас не в "нераспознавании".